# forward declaration cpp invalid use of incomplete type

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I am writing this test code in a single TypeConversion.cpp file with no header files I am forward declaring Counter2 and trying to invoke method on it which counter2.getA(); which is giving me compile time error invalid use of incomplete type 'class Counter2' Is there any way to resolve this error?

Is there any sense of forward declaration in .cpp file or is it useful in header files only.

```
//TypeConversion.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Counter2;

class Counter {

public:
int count;


public :
const int* getCount() const{return &(this->count);}

void setCount() {

    this->count=10;

}

// Pre-increment
Counter operator++() {
    this->count++;

    return (*this);
}
//Post increment
Counter& operator++(int){
    Counter dummy;
    dummy.count=this->count;//(*this).n
    this->count++;
    return dummy;
}

 const Counter& modify() {
    this->count=111;
    return *this;
}

Counter()  {
    this->count=0;
    //this->array[5]={1,1,2,3,4};
}

/*Counter(Counter2 &counter2) {
    this->count= counter2.getA() + counter2.getB();
}*/

istream& operator>>(istream& in) {

    in>>this->count;
    return in;
}

void operator=(Counter2 &counter2) {
    this->count = counter2.getA() + counter2.getB();
}

/*  int& operator[](int index){
    return this->array[index];
}*/

};

class Counter2 {
private:
int a ,b;
public:
Counter2() {
    this->a=10;
    this->b=20;
}
Counter2(Counter &c) {
    this->a=c.count;
    this->b=c.count;
}

int getA()  {return this->a;}
int getB()  {return this->b;}

operator Counter() {
    Counter c;
    return c;
}

};

int main() {
cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
Counter2 c2;
Counter c=c2;
//c=c2;
cout<<endl<<*(c.getCount());
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

forward declaration is used in the header files to e.g. be able to hold an object of the class. But once you want to access methods or members of this class (in your .cpp) you have to include the correct header with definitions.

Comment: Thanks for explanation!! What Can I do to resolve error in code specified above?

Comment: Forward declarations can be used in source files as well (but are rarely useful there). And you won't be able to hold an object of an incomplete class. You need the full definition for that, just like for calling a member function. What you can do with an incomplete class, is declare pointers and references to them.

Comment: @user2206366: in your case you have to define `void Counter::operator=(Counter2 &counter2)` after class `Counter2`'s definition.

Comment: @Jarod42 Can you provide an example of that?

Comment: @trusktr: Like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d50e46bc8398bce).